# Clicked "Off" on full screen button and now my screen is black. What do I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please help me, I went into options on Minecraft and clicked full screen off and now my screen is black and I can't play.

Comment: F11 is the keyboard shortcut for toggling fullscreen.  Try hitting that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you could try and do.

**1. Close full screen.**

Minecraft's default hotkey for toggling full screen is <kbd>F11</kbd>. Hitting this key should bring it back to windowed mode, where you will be able to close the window from there.

(It may change depending on if you have altered the keyboard inputs in Minecraft before)

**2. Tab out.**

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on your keyboard (on Mac use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>). This will switch your window to another open window, or the desktop, depending on what you have open.

From here you can right-click on the window tab, and choose to close the window.

**3. Open the Task Manager**

Another option is to open the Task Manager. By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (works on both Windows and Mac) at the same time, this will bring up a screen with several options on it. Select "Task Manager" from this list, which you can then choose the "Minecraft" option from the Applications tab, and click on "End Process"

You can also open the task manager directly by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Windows only) at the same time.

Comment: All commands will only work in a windows environment (beside F11). I think that one cannot answer the question correctly, after all, the user might have pulled the screen's power cord. ;) – @kyle should really add more information to the question.

Comment: @Zeta, I doubt that he had turned the screen off. As he states in the question: **"I went into options on Minecraft and clicked full screen off"**. This is the cause of something within Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the alt button and press tab. Go to the task bar and close Minecraft by right clicking on Minecraft and click close. Open it and try again. Hope this helped :)

Comment: You really think that the user was able to post on Arqade with a new account, but doesn't know about alt tab?

Comment: @Zeta - quite possibly, yes.

Comment: Yes, if he was using a separate computer to ask.